# Insert a record into a table from a VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

**Using:** SQL Server, SSMS 2008, T-SQL

**Goal:** I want to create a VIEW where whenever it is called (for example `select * from VIEW`), it will insert a record into another table that basically states the current datetime. The purpose for this is to track how often the VIEW is called.

**What I've Tried:** I tried running something like the below VIEW pseudo-code but it failed.

**Question:** Is this goal possible?

```
USE DATABASE
GO
/****** Object:  View SCHEMA.VIEW1   Script Date: 08/10/2016 17:52:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

 CREATE VIEW SCHEMA.VIEW1 AS

 --Step 1: Update the LogTable with the current datetime so I will know that the VIEW was called on this date/time

 INSERT INTO DATABASE.SCHEMA.LogTable (DATE)
 VALUES (GETDATE())

 --Step 2: The "actual" VIEW code, select all records from TABLE1 (just as an example)

 SELECT *
 FROM DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE1

 GO
```

Comment: Do you need to call the view by selecting from it? Could you not, for example, create a procedure that selects from the view and inserts into the log table and call that instead?

Comment: @ZLK I want to keep the `insert into` in the VIEW code as opposed to a procedure to not have to give execute permissions to all employees on the database. Instead, they'd be given write permissions specifically to the LogTable.

Comment: Well it's not really possible in a view, as far as I'm aware. But I'm not sure what the issue would be with giving users permission for the procedure if it does the same thing.

Comment: @ZLK That is a good question. Allowing them to have write access to just the one table prevents them from doing anything except writing to that one table of course, whereas granting them execute access allows the users to execute any sproc that we have in the database.

Comment: @ZLK I think you and Biscuits below may be right about it not being possible...still researching.

Comment: You can grant execute on a single stored procedure (not all of them) to certain users (or just to public, if you want).

Comment: @ZLK Hmm...okay that is very interesting. I will certainly consider that if this idea does not work...which seems likely. I really appreciate your suggestion. I wish I could accept that as the answer, but it technically isn't for the way my question is worded, though it may serve even more useful. Much appreciated again.

Comment: You can also just create a condensed view of the data they need access to and grant specific users SELECT on the view. Similar to granting EXECUTE on a SP

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  Views can only read data.

Comment: I thought you were saying you can't insert into a view. I misread

Answer (score 0):

First thing is first, you cannot insert record to another table when defining a view. But you can create SERVER AUDIT to audit the SELECT statement. Query is as follows, please modify it accordingly :)

In the 'master' database,

```
CREATE SERVER AUDIT [select_audit] 
TO FILE(FILEPATH='E:\folder_name\') 
WITH (ON_FAILURE=FAIL_OPERATION, QUEUE_DELAY=0);

ALTER SERVER AUDIT [select_audit] WITH (STATE=ON);
```

In the target database where your VIEW exists,

```
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [spec_test]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [select_audit]
ADD (SELECT ON OBJECT::[SCHEMAname].[VIEW name] BY [USER name])
```

Do the select operation on your VIEW

```
select * from dbo.view_test
```

Check the folder as well as this system table to see the logging information. You can also insert this info into your auditing table.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_file_audits
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('E:\folder_name\*', NULL, NULL);
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_audit_status
```

[image]